# How to write a regex that matches at least 10 digits and can have only digits and exclamation mark

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to write a regex that matches the following conditions:

1. At least 10 digits
2. Can contain only digits and exclamation mark

I can write a regex that matches ten digits like this:

```
^([0-9]){10,}$
```

Or that matches only digits and exclamation mark:

```
^[0-9!]$
```

But I can't figure out how to join those two together.

Here is the valid example:

```
152!1582!!1827
```

Here is the invalid example:

```
4!!!!!!!!!!!!!3!
```

Comment: You mean digits, not numbers. And, why did you leave out the parentheses and braces from the second attempt?

Comment: There has been many similar questions. Use a `(?=(?:\D*\d){10})` lookahead anchored at the beginning. The consuming pattern will remain `^[\d!]+$`. Combine them and you get `^(?=(?:\D*\d){10})[\d!]+$`. If you only allow 1 `!`, do it like `^(?=(?:\D*\d){10})\d*(?:!\d*)?$`

Comment: Can the exclamation marks be interspersed with the digits or must they be placed in specific relation to the digits?

Comment: @trincot, yes, digits. I left them out because the regex will match if I'll have ten exclamation marks, which is not what I want

Comment: So 10 or more digits and if more than 10 you are allowed one or more exclamation marks? Or 10 characters where at least one is a digit and the rest may be digits or exclamation mark?

Comment: @BJBlack, they can be intercepted.

Comment: Is there a minimum number of exclamation marks required?

Comment: interspersed. Not intercepted

Comment: Digits, not numbers.

Comment: @trincot, no, there can be none. Right, digits

Comment: Please give valid and invalid examples

Comment: @Aaron: That does not have to be the best solution anyway, since we just do not know exact specifications.

Comment: In that case, you want two regexes: One to validate that you have only valid chars, another to remove (via string.replace()) any non-numbers and just get the length of that string to count your digits. Much simpler than overloading one regex.  Two simple regexes >> one complicated one.

Comment: Maximums - are you saying any number of exclamation marks in any position is valid as long as there are also at least 10 digits?

Comment: @mplungjan: No, mine and Amow's are different patterns.

Comment: @nnnnnn, yes, you are right

Comment: Ok, try [`^(?=(?:\D*\d){10})\d+(?:!+\d+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/vM9qX4/2)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, thanks a lot, I'll give a try

Comment: You'd better just explain what you need in the question, otherwise, we just guess. The accepted answer assumes you may have `!` anywhere in the string and as many as you want. That is not clear from your examples.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I don't have clear requirements myself. I was just wondering how I can combine those two conditions. What does your last suggested regexp different?

Comment: It does not allow leading/trailing exclamation marks.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, I see, thanks. I'll try understand your regexp and learn something new from it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`^!*([0-9]!*){10,}$`

may be start with zero or more `!`, and then have at least 10 repeat of the form `a digit and zero or more !`

Comment: Or the same thing but slightly shorter: `^!*(\d!*){10,}$`.

Comment: Aha, so the trailing `!`s are also allowed. That was not mentioned in the question.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew - Yeah, the OP did eventually confirm that in a comment in reply to my comment above, but didn't update the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

`^!*(\d!*){10,}$` should satisfy your needs.

```js
function validate() {
  var field = document.getElementById("inputField");
  console.log(/^!*(\d!*){10,}$/.test(field.value));
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="inputField">
<button onclick="validate()">Validate</button>
```